# Does not async / await call in FastAPI & Python go to thread pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, fastapi

I implemented my simple server on Python and FastAPI and currently learn more about async / await work in FastAPI. The question is based on this [doc](https://github.com/zhanymkanov/fastapi-best-practices#7-dont-make-your-routes-async-if-you-have-only-blocking-io-operations) and it is unclear does async calls go to a thread pool or not.

I am familiar with concept of coroutines by extensively using them in Kotlin / Android. In this context [coroutines are organised in some state machine](https://gelassen.github.io/blog/2020/09/05/kotlin-coroutines-overview.html) and there is no usage of the thread pool. Is it the same in Python / FastApi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs you linked, it appears that async things run on a single even loop (non-threaded) and sync things run on a thread pool. This makes sense since the async paradigm is single threaded by design (in python anyway).

I remind you that in python threads are not concurrent, so there won't be a performance boost from using a pool for async operations since they happen one at a time anyway

Comment: Thanks, I just look for confirmation I understood it right.